# why boinc now on ubuntu 12.04 just run 2 tasks?

Tags: 12.04, boinc

i use to have when i have the computer turn on and was idle having more than 2 tasks running at same time.. but now this is not happens and it is enable at maximum of 2 tasks at same time, i don know why.

also i was able 2 do that on ubuntu 11.10 not sure if is the same using boinc on ubuntu 11.10.

so why this happens?

and how can i set up boinc 2 run more than just 2 tasks at same time in ubuntu 12.04 beta?

Answer (score 1):

The number of simultaneous tasks depends on the number of CPU cores you have. A quad-core CPU will run 4 tasks (and an extra 5th task if you have a GPU), a dual-core will run 2, etc.

Each task runs on each CPU core, and there is little point in running additional tasks beyond your CPU core count: they won't run any faster, and might run *slower* due to polling/switching.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened for me on 2 different 4-core Xeons, and a 6-core AMD Phenom. Turns out there is a setting in `/var/lib/boinc-client/global_prefs.xml`:

```
<max_cpus>2</max_cpus>
```

After changing that to 4 resp. 6, and `sudo service boinc-client restart`, all my cores were used.